# Recording Analog Data in Optical Disc Using Laser Beam Mechanism

Tags: acoustics, optical-materials, laser-interaction

Is it possible to storing/writing any Analog Audio Signal (i.e. Vinyl Record & etc) into a little bigger and thicker **Optical Disc** as compared to the other conventional **Compact Disc** while using the "**Laser Beam Technology**", over the ***aluminium layer*** for **Writing** (burning/melting) and **Reading** to make it as ***Dust Proof** along with ***Zero Friction**** altogether?